# Can't wrap my head around the behavior of this logical operator

Tags: javascript

I was messing around with some simple exercises and found something that I thought acted quite odd. I wrote a very simple HTML form that when a user enters their name, if it was `Bob` or `Alice` it would great them. If it was another name, it would say `I don't know you.` So, my thought  was to use a logical operator to compare the username that was entered. Here is my code:

```
<h1>This is the practice space</h1>
    <div id="output">
        <label>what is your name?</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <button type="button" onclick="getName()">Send it through!</button>
        <span id="output-name"></span>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getName(){

            var userName = document.getElementById('name').value;

            if(userName === 'Alice' || 'Bob'){
                document.getElementById('output-name').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + userName + '! Glad to have you!';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('output-name').innerHTML = 'I don\'t know you.';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

To  me this says "if `userName` is equal to `Alice`, then true, If not, if `userName` equals to `Bob` then true. If not, then `I don't know you.` That is not the case. Everything that I enter is passing as true and nothing is passing as false. Can anyone make any sense of this?

By the way, I read through the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) specifically to find out the logic in these logical operators. I thought by what I read, my code should work.

Comment: Since any string is not false, your condition gets always passed.
But this works: `if (userName === 'Alice' || userName === 'Bob') { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you're not checking anything against `'Bob'`.

Change:

```
if(userName === 'Alice' || 'Bob')
```

To:

```
if(userName === 'Alice' || userName === 'Bob')
```

The reason your current code returns true all the time is because strings, unless empty, are [*truthy*](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/). `'Bob'` evaluates to `true`, so your `if` statement is quite literally saying: *If the username is equal to Alice, or if this is true, then...*. `if ('Bob')` will always be true.

Comment: `knowUsers.indexOf(userName) != -1` form could also come handy.

Comment: +1 well explained, i was halfway through an answer when yours came up :(

Comment: @James Donnelly Wow! That makes perfect sense. Thank you for the clear explanation.